# Where I can find data to help build family trees?

Tags: data-request

I need public data about persons / parent-child relationships, especially relating to the past. I am creating an awesome family tree app, and I want to help people to build their extended family tree.

Where I am able to reach public global / local databases to show use person relationship information? Is there any available global distribution system I could use?

Comment: I'm not an expert in this arena but I would start by going to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_genealogy_software#Genealogical_features and looking at their sites to see what their data sources are. Some probably have none while others offer a look up service.

Comment: I think the key to build family tree is, after user used all info based on family memory, can you find and use matching point with other users' family tree, and / or App feeds you with data comes form digitalised birth / marriage certificates

Answer (score 7):

There are a lot of paid services that provide this type of information, such as [Ancestry.com](http://Ancestry.com).  They are unlikely to offer access to their highly curated content.

However, the Church of Latter Day Saints at [FamilySearch](https://familysearch.org/) does provide a free service for others to use.  That site provides [developer resources](https://familysearch.org/developers/) specifically for people like you, and encourages others to build apps using APIs and accessing their data.

Data formats are described in more detail [here](https://familysearch.org/developers/docs/api/media-types).

Good luck!